# Python. Как сравнить два текста за исключением изменяемых мест

Tags: python, python-3.x, diff

Прошу гуру рассмотреть задачу, мой собственный вариант решения и посоветовать как это можно улучшить.

### Задача

Есть два текста, в частности, два конфига маршрутизатора Cisco, полученных через некоторое время один от другого. Нужно определить, одинаковы ли эти конфиги и предоставить интерфейс, показывающий различия.

#### Проблемные моменты

В конфигах есть места, которые могут отличаться, но которые не влияют на условие одинаковости, например время последней записи на диск. Такие места не должны быть помечены, как отличающиеся. И эта информация нам неважна.

Также следует скрыть ключи и пароли, хотя было бы полезно регистрировать их различия

#### Пример текстов

Два текста, которые должны быть автоматически определены как одинаковые

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 33530 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 23:58:33 EST Fri Nov 22 2019 by baz
! NVRAM config last updated at 00:32:38 EST Sat Nov 23 2019 by bar
!
version 15.3
service timestamps debug datetime msec localtime show-timezone year
service timestamps log datetime msec localtime show-timezone year
service password-encryption
no platform punt-keepalive disable-kernel-core
```

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 33530 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 10:00:00 EST Fri Dec  6 2019 by leo
! NVRAM config last updated at 10:00:05 EST Fri Dec  6 2019 by leo
! NVRAM config last updated at 10:12:25 EST Fri Dec  6 2019 by fix
!
version 15.3
service timestamps debug datetime msec localtime show-timezone year
service timestamps log datetime msec localtime show-timezone year
service password-encryption
no platform punt-keepalive disable-kernel-core
```

Comment: Вы Ансибл модуль не прбовали реверс инженерить? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ios_facts_module.html

Comment: @Hellseher, задача, на самом деле, более широкая. Нужно снять конфиги и вывод нескольких команд на всех железках Cisco перед и после запланированного отключения электричества. И автоматом сравнить, всё ли осталось как было. Так что нужно иметь решение "в общем". Но идея интересная, надо будет взглянуть - спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Одно из возможных решений - нормализация текстов: удаление или замещение определенными символами частей текста, которые не влияют на условие одинаковости.

В частности для конфигов Cisco можно предложить такой код:

```python
import re

_normalize_whiteout_config_regexes = tuple(map(lambda x: re.compile(x, re.MULTILINE), [
    # скрываем когда и кем изменён
    r'^! Last configuration change at (.+?) by (.+?)$',
    # Cisco Nexus - скрываем текущее время
    r'^!Time: (.+)$',
    # all - скрываем ключи и пароли
    r' (?:password|secret|key) \d ([^\s]+)',
    r' (?:auth|priv) .*?0x([^\s]+)',
]))

_normalize_remove_config_regexes = tuple(map(lambda x: re.compile(x, re.MULTILINE), [
    # Удаляем всю строку, так как их пожет быть несколько
    r'(^! NVRAM config last updated at .+? by .+?\r?\n)',
    # Cisco Nexus - удаляем всю строку, чтобы сравнивать
    # running и startup конфиги
    r'(^!Startup config saved at: .+?\r?\n)',
    # all - удаляем кусок команды, чтобы сравнивать
    # running и startup конфиги
    r'show (running|startup)-config',
]))

def _normalize_match(_match, blackout_mode=True):
    """
    It blacks out or removes text in the matched groups.
    :param _match: match found by re.sub
    :param blackout_mode: Default: True
        True: all text characters in the matched groups will be replaced with '#'
        False: text in the matched groups will be removed
    """

    position = 0
    offset = _match.start()
    text = _match.group()
    _result = []
    for index in range(1, len(_match.groups()) + 1):
        start, end = _match.span(index)
        _result.append(text[position:start - offset])
        if blackout_mode:
            _result.append('#' * (end - start + 1))
        position = end - offset
    _result.append(text[position:])
    return ''.join(_result)


def cisco_normalize_config(out):

    # Скрываем части текста
    for regex in _normalize_whiteout_config_regexes:
        out = regex.sub(_normalize_match, out)

    # Удаляем части текста
    for regex in _normalize_remove_config_regexes:
        out = regex.sub(lambda x: _normalize_match(x, blackout_mode=False), out)

    return out


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("cisco_show_startup_config.txt") as f:
        _out = f.read()
    print(cisco_normalize_config(_out))
```

Результат нормализации обоих текстов из вопроса - одинаков:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 33530 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at ############################# by ####
!
version 15.3
service timestamps debug datetime msec localtime show-timezone year
service timestamps log datetime msec localtime show-timezone year
service password-encryption
no platform punt-keepalive disable-kernel-core
```

Соответственно, команда diff не найдёт отличий.
А если отличия будут найдены, то они могут быть показаны при помощи различных существующих решений под Python или JavaScript